# Why get multiple console log outputs from a function in my React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, promise, console.log

I created this function in my React app to fetch a `url` and check the status.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const fetchStatusCode = (url: string) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<string | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchStatus = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(url);
      return response.statusText;
    };

    fetchStatus().then((res) => setData(res));
  }, []);

  return data;
};

export default fetchStatusCode;
```

I can then use it like this in a component:
`console.log('Status', fetchStatusCode('http://my-site.com/abc/token'));`

In the browser console I get:
`Status null`
`Status null`
`Status Ok`

Is that the intended behaviour? Why get multiple console log outputs (first 2 times `null` and then `OK`)?

Comment: This is indeed expected behavior.  React re-renders the component(s) when relevant state is updated.  If this *didn't* happen then all you'd ever get back from this function is `null`, which wouldn't be particularly useful.

Comment: @David thanks. Because I then use this function to send a custom header with Apollo Client link construtor: `const isOk = fetchStatusCode('http://my-site.com/abc/token') === 'OK';` and use the condition like `headers: {
        ...headers,
        'custom-header': isOk ? 'MyName' : null,
      },`.
So is this function correct for this use case?

Comment: The usage seems a bit mis-structured, but if it works in testing then it at least works.  Personally I would (1) rename `fetchStatusCode` to something like `useStatusCode` to clearly identify it as a React hook, (2) invoke it at the start of the component as: `const statusCode = useStatusCode('http://my-site.com/abc/token');`, and (3) use `statusCode` as a dependency in a `useEffect` call to conditionally perform the Apollo Client operation.

Comment: @David [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74292659/create-react-custom-hook-instead-of-helper-function) I created a new question. Hope you can guide me a bit and you see some key points to improve and refactor. Thanks

Comment: @David regarding 'statusCode as a dependency in a useEffect'. Can you help me with that in the linked question above?

Answer (score 0):

In React, the view flows from the state. Whenever the state changes, the components that it may correspond to will re-render. This will include a component and all of its children, if the component directly uses state with `useState` inside it - or if the component is using a custom hook and state inside the custom hook changes.

When a component re-renders, the function associated with the component will run again so React can determine what new JSX elements it returns given the different state. So seeing something like

> `Status null` `Status null` `Status Ok`

is normal - these must have resulted from

`Status null` - The parent component just mounted, so there's a log

`Status null` - The parent component just re-rendered, so its function runs again, and there's a log

`Status Ok` - The state inside `fetchStatusCode` just changed, resulting in the parent component re-rendering, resulting in another log