# Create React custom hook instead of helper function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, fetch-api, apollo-client, react-custom-hooks

I created a helper function in my React app to fetch the status after fetching a `url`:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const fetchStatusCode = (url: string) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<string | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchStatus = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(url);
      return response.statusText;
    };

    fetchStatus().then((res) => setData(res));
  }, []);

  return data;
};

export default fetchStatusCode;
```

I then use this to conditionally send a custom header in [Apollo Client Link](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/link/apollo-link-http/) operation:

```
// Apollo Client component file

const isOkStatus = fetchStatusCode('http://my-site.com/abc/token') === 'OK';

const myCustomLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
    return {
      headers: {
        ...headers,
        'my-header': isOkStatus ? 'MyName' : null,
      },
    };
  });

const client: ApolloClient<NormalizedCacheObject> = new ApolloClient({
    link: from([errorLink, myCustomLink, httpLink]),
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
    typeDefs,
  });
```

Are there ways to refactor this and maybe create a custom React hook instead of a helper function?

**Update:**

1. I changed the function to a hook by renaming it to `useStatusCode`
2. I use this hook in the Apollo Client file like:
   `const statusCode = useStatusCode('http://my-site.com/abc/token');`
3. Maybe one thing to refactor? Use statusCode as a dependency in a useEffect call to conditionally perform the Apollo Client operation. How do I do this in my example above?

Comment: Other than the fact that it's not using the naming convention of starting with `use`, it already *is* a custom hook. A custom hook is a function that calls other hooks, and fetchStatusCode does that. I recommend changing the name, but is there anything else you want to change?

Comment: @NicholasTower thanks! I changed it and added an update to my question. Do you know how about point 3?